# how to make form calls php only if javascript function returns true?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Pretty much the title everything works fine but the problem is when I press submit it calls the PHP function even if the JavaScript function returned `false`.

```
<script >
    function validateForm(){
        var formData = document.forms["Signup Form"]["FirstName"].value;
        var div = document.getElementById("FirstNameDiv")
        if(formData==null || formData=="")
        {
            div.innerHTML = "<p>" + "invalid" + "</p>"
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form name="Signup Form" method="POST" action="<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" onsubmit="return validateForm();" ) ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after setting div.innerHTML, which is causing the code to fail and not return false. Try:

```
if(formData==null || formData=="")
{
    div.innerHTML = "<p>" + "invalid" + "</p>";
    return false;
}
```

On second look, you are also missing a semicolon on your div declaration:

```
var div = document.getElementById("FirstNameDiv"); #< Added semicolon
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the submit button i use on my forms. It should call the function and not post if it returns false.

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="sbmt" onclick=" return validateForm()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons after `var div = document.getElementById("FirstNameDiv")` and after `div.innerHTML = "<p>" + "invalid" + "</p>"`

Also, replace `) ">` with just `>`

How do you know it's returning false?  Have you verified this by calling `validateForm()` from the console?